# Codeblocks graphics.h executing but not working

Tags: c, codeblocks, bgi

I am using graphics.h provided from first link that says "Download WinBGIm here" [here](http://winbgim.codecutter.org/), I have copy-pasted and edited all the required files, code is working properly but it is not able to launch any BGI output window.

my gcc compiler version is gcc.exe (tdm-1) 5.1.0

I am attaching my code and screenshots of code blocks below

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include<conio.h>
// driver code
int main()
{
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "");
    line(150, 150, 450, 150);
    line(150, 200, 450, 200);
    line(150, 250, 450, 250);
    getch();
    closegraph();
    return 0;

}
```

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What does your debugger say? What line causes the crash?

Comment: I am adding it in post @HolyBlackCat thanks for help

Comment: The picture shows that the debugger has failed to start. I suggest running `gdb` (the debugger) manually from the command line. You'll have to learn how to do that sooner or later anyway.

Comment: If you are using Turbo C++ or Borland C++, I recommend using their IDEs.  Using CodeBlocks is complicating the issue (like having to include the proper libraries for graphics).

Comment: Reminder:  C and C++ are distinct languages.  Which single language are you using?  I do not recommend mixing the languages, as that adds more complexity to your program.  Please update your language tags as appropriate.

Comment: turbo c++ is a very unreliable software, it stutters and lags, and then I am unable to save my file and I can't even copy-paste in turbo, that's why I am not using turbo

Comment: Please specify **in your question** what exactly you downloaded from http://winbgim.codecutter.org/. Pre-built version or source code? Which versions of MingW and GCC do you use? The WinBGIm page looks fairly old. There might be incompatibilities with current build tools.

Comment: @Bodo the first link on the site that says "Download WinBGIm here"

Comment: My friend, you can write perfect code and if the library you are using has been compiled for a different compiler (and for most "modern" ports of the BGI library fronted by graphics.h, that compiler is GCC 3. You likely have GCC 4 or better), there are no guarantees. The library was alsi writen to target operating systems and graphics hardware from around 2003-or-so. It very likely cannot talk to anything you'd have in a PC built within the last ten years.

Comment: @user4581301 yes, i have gcc 5+ but I am able to run in turboc , I am trying to get code blocks running because turbo c is very unreliable,it stutters and stucks often and I lose my file

Comment: Ah ha! I missed that link. Yes, if you are using winbgim, that stopped working reliably around Windows 7. If you need to use 40 year-old tools like BGI for a class, you'll have to duplicate what the instructor is going to use to mark your assignments otherwise all bets are off. You could use a newer port of BGI like [BGI_SDL](http://libxbgi.sourceforge.net/) that does work correctly with modern PCs and compilers, but you'll have no guarantees that what you wrote will work on the marking computer.

Comment: @Tarandeepsingh Please [edit] your question and add all requested information or clarification there instead of answering in comments. You didn't answer the questions about the versions. If you are not using MingW 5.0.3 and GCC 3.4.5 as stated next to the download link, the pre-built library might be incompatible with your environment.

Comment: It's probably too late for you, but politely try to convince your educational institution to teach with newer tools. You may be able to save future students from entering the workforce armed with the digital equivalent of flint knives.

Comment: @Bodo oh, i didn't read that comment completely, ill surely update the post with info , I am able to use graphics.h in turboc and its using the same compiler but its stuttering and stops working often so i am not using turboc

Comment: As for you, code with your choice of modern IDEs against BGI_SDL. and get the code working correctly with the modern tools. Then take the same code and make sure it still runs in Turbo C, correcting what you need to. This will be a much faster path. I do the same thing when writing for embedded systems. It's a lot easier to beat the logic errors out of a program with PC tools and do the final grunt work on the harder-to-use platform.

Comment: @user4581301 BGI_SDL have same syntax ?

Comment: I guess  user4581301's recommendation is better, but if you really want to use WinBGIm with a different compiler version (and probably MinGW version) you could try to download the source code and compile it with your tools versions.

Comment: If it doesn't it would be useless. Compare the graphics.h headers to be sure, and iff BGI_SDL added anything new, don't use it.

Comment: http://libxbgi.sourceforge.net/ . If that doesn't work, build from source: https://github.com/genpfault/sdl-bgi  @Bodo Tarandeep would probably learn more making WinBGIm compile and link under modern Windows and compilers than they'll learn in the rest of the course. I wholeheartedly approve, but I also want the poor guy to have time left over to pass their class. [Here's my piece on the topic from a couple years ago (and my introduction to BGI_SDL)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49804255/4581301)

Comment: thanks everyone for helping me out! ill try bgi sdl and see what happens, turboc would be last resort

Comment: In my not-so-humble opinion, Turbo C shouldn't have to be a resort. Not in 2020. Leave it in the 1980s where it belongs. It can't be that hard to update the syllabus, rubric, and tools to something from this millennium that'll actually be relevant to graduates. Charging people to learn this stuff should be considered fraud.

Comment: @user4581301 I agree but other cultures have different objectives. The Hindustan Ambassador car was based on the Morris Oxford manufactured in the UK from 1956 to 1959, but only went out of production in India in 2014 (with few modifications). If you are *given* say a working Dell 286 then that will ***not*** be thrown away but used. And yes, it *can* be hard to update.

Comment: @WeatherVane Screenshots indicate that they have Windows10 installed... How do you afford hardware that requires at least 2GB of RAM and 20-30GB of disk space to even boot but not compilers that are literally free? They could install linux and hack away with gcc 9 while having 1900MB of RAM and 28GB of disk space leftover that they could use to install KDE or something. And that's assuming terrible economical situation, and I don't know about you, but being able to buy 100+ euro OS is opposite of that.

Comment: @Yamirui i have mint linux in vm, i can give it a try if you could help me with a "guide" to use graphics.h or bgi_sdl in mint?